# Scriptures that suggest there will be things found in the latter days to support the Bible?

Tags: bible, prophecy, verse-identification

Someone made a comment a while back that the Bible mentions that in the latter days, things will be discovered, eg.  archeology etc, that prove many of things in the Bible as being true.  I am pretty sure I have ran across this as well, but can't find it now.

It's **not** Daniel 12:4 that I was thinking of, but I really can't recall now, maybe it was.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Scriptures that suggest there will be things found in the latter days to support the Bible?**

The Books of Maccabees is considered Canon according to the Orthodox and Catholic Churches. In [2 Maccabees 1-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Maccabees%202&version=NRSVCE), Scriptures state that the Ark of the Covenant, the Tent and the Altar of Incense will be discovered in the future.

> **Jeremiah Hides the Tent, Ark, and Altar**
>
> 2 One finds in the records that the prophet Jeremiah ordered those who were being deported to take some of the fire, as has been mentioned, 2 and that the prophet, after giving them the law, instructed those who were being deported not to forget the commandments of the Lord, or to be led astray in their thoughts on seeing the gold and silver statues and their adornment. 3 And with other similar words he exhorted them that the law should not depart from their hearts.
>
> 4 It was also in the same document that the prophet, having received an oracle, ordered that the tent and the ark should follow with him, and that he went out to the mountain where Moses had gone up and had seen the inheritance of God. 5 Jeremiah came and found a cave-dwelling, and he brought there the tent and the ark and the altar of incense; then he sealed up the entrance. 6 Some of those who followed him came up intending to mark the way, but could not find it. 7 When Jeremiah learned of it, he rebuked them and declared: **“The place shall remain unknown until God gathers his people together again and shows his mercy.** 8 Then the Lord will disclose these things, and the glory of the Lord and the cloud will appear, as they were shown in the case of Moses, and as Solomon asked that the place should be specially consecrated.”

I am sure others are to be found in the Bible!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can find is in Daniel:

> Daniel 12:4 But you, Daniel, roll up and seal the words of the scroll
> until the time of the end. Many will go here and there to increase
> knowledge.”

This implies that mysteries in Daniel's prophecies have been obfuscated. Their full import will not be made clear until "the time of the end". Revelation chapters 5 and 6 speak of a scroll with seven seals that only Jesus can break. The opening of those seals may correspond to Daniel's seal.

If you take Revelation's seals and Daniel's together, then you get a revelation of power and of additional wisdom, to occur near the end of the age.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel 12:4,10 says,
"*… shut up the words, and seal the book, even to the time of the end: many shall run to and fro, and knowledge shall be increased.
… none of the wicked shall understand; but the wise shall understand*".

This could be interpreted as a time when people are able to travel everywhere and large amounts of new knowledge are available.
(E.g. our current age, with modern science, technology, transportation, archaeology, etc., and vast libraries of information available in everyone's pocket.)

But only those few that have true wisdom (using the Bible and God's spirit as their guide) will understand how to put it together to make sense of it all.

The Bible contains many prophecies of the end times, but only the wise will be able to recognize that they are being fulfilled now.